# EM tensor in de Sitter spacetime

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, stress-energy-momentum-tensor, de-sitter-spacetime

The energy momentum tensor for a particle in Minkowski space at position $\textbf{r}_A$ is given by:

$$T^{\mu \nu} = \frac{p^{\mu}p^{\nu}}{E/c^2}\delta(\textbf{r} - \textbf{r}_A)$$

I want to understand how this changes in de Sitter spacetime, especially when I write the metric as $g_{\mu \nu} = a^2 \eta_{\mu \nu}$ i.e. I am using coordinates $(\tau,\textbf{x})$ where $\tau$ is the conformal time defined as $\frac{dt}{d\tau} = a$ and $\eta_{\mu \nu}$ is the Minkowski metric. So far, I have the following.

Since the 4 momentum is defined with respect to the proper time, suppose I have proper time $\lambda$ then the 4 momentum in Minkowski is:

$$p^{\mu}_M = m \frac{d x^{\mu}}{d\lambda} = m\frac{d}{d\lambda}(ct,\textbf{x}) = m\frac{dt}{d\lambda}(c,\textbf{v}) = m\gamma (c,\textbf{v}) = m\gamma u^{\mu}_M .$$

In de Sitter, in the coordinates mentioned above, we would have:

$$p^{\mu}_{dS} = m \frac{d}{d\lambda}(ct,\textbf{x}) = m\frac{dt}{d\lambda}(c,\textbf{v}) = m\frac{d\tau}{d\lambda}\frac{dt}{d\tau}(c,\textbf{v}) = a(m\gamma u^{\mu}_M) = a p^{\mu}_M.$$

Therefore, when I try to calculate the EM tensor, I know that the momenta will give me an $a^2$. However, I have two questions.

1. I'm not sure how the energy in the denominator will change. Isn't the energy simply one of the components of the four vector?
2. Further, the position $\text{r}_A$ will now refer to the co-moving
   coordinate right? So should the $\delta$ function be replaced by
   $\delta(a\textbf{r} - a\textbf{r}_A) = \frac{\delta(\textbf{r} -
   \textbf{r}_A)}{|a|}$

Comment: Energy-momentum tensor in general relativity can be written in a covariant form: https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/644423/221111